# Lucee URI encoding issue (cyrillic)

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, railo, lucee

I just moved one of our core apps from Windows+IIS+Coldfusion to Ubuntu+Apache+Lucee. The first big problem is the URI  encoding for exotic alphabets.

For example, trying to reach this url `http://www.example.com/ru/Солнцезащитные-очки/saint-laurent/` results in this record in the Apache access.log:

```
http://www.example.com/ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/saint-laurent/
```

Well, I think that's correctly url-encoded. Then I use a rewrite rule in .htaccess file to get that portion of the url (the cyrillic one) in a url query string parameter (let's say "foo").

Using cflog to dump it, I see in the application log:

```
/index.cfm?foo=Ð¾ÑÐºÐ¸-Ð´Ð»Ñ-Ð·ÑÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ&
```

...which is obviously wrong, because what I need is the original string, in utf-8 cyrillic.

I tried to put URIEncoding parameter in my server.xml tomcat http connector, with no results:

```
<Connector port="8888" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" 
                URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

How can I get my url parameter in UTF-8?

Comment: The first thing I would try would be to isolate tomcat and test that directly. i.e. try http://hostname:8888/index.cfm?foo=Солнцезащитные-очки. If that works correctly - your issue is on the Apache/mod_rewrite side. This might help focusing the question. If still a problem, you could also look at the tomcat access logs for further isolation (perhaps it is indeed a lucee issue rather than a tomcat one).

Comment: I tried and it works if I directly call lucee passing the cyrillic parameter as you wrote. So... is that an apache mod_rewrite issue? Why does it change my encoding?!?

Comment: That I can't tell you (not my area of knowledge). But you could reframe the question as an Apache / Mod rewrite one and provide some details so that some experts in that area might help (though it looks as though you shouldn't be using these URLs at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Source: http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/kieranshaw/entry/utf-8_internationalisation_with

> Apache
>
> Generally you don't need to worry about Apache as it shouldn't be
>   messing with your HMTL or URLs. However, if you are doing some
>   proxying with mod_proxy then you might need to have a think about
>   this. We use mod_proxy to do proxying from Apache through to Tomcat.
>   If you've got encoded characters in URL that you need to convert into
>   some query string for your underlying app then you're going to have a
>   strange little problem.
>
> If you have a URL coming into Apache that looks like this:
>
> http://mydomain/%E4%B8%AD.doc and you have a mod_rewrite/proxy rule
>   like this:
>
> RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mydomain:8080/filedownload/?filename=$1
>   [QSA,L,P]
>
> Unfortunately the $1 is going to get mangled during the rewrite. QSA
>   (QueryStringAppend) actually deals with these characters just fine and
>   will send this through untouched, but when you grab a bit of the URL
>   such as my $1 here then the characters get mangled as Apache tries to
>   do some unescaping of its own into ISO-8859-1, but it's UTF-8 not
>   ISO-8859-1 so it doesn't work properly. So, to keep our special
>   characters in UTF-8, we'll escape it back again.
>
> RewriteMap escape int:escape RewriteRule ^/(.*)
>   http://mydomain:8080/filedownload/?filename=${escape:$1} [QSA,L,P]
>
> Take a look at your rewrite logs to see if this is working.

Really hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

The best is **not** to use cyrillic in URI under any circumstances. That is very bad practice to include something except ASCII in there. I'm telling you from here Moscow, Russia as the native Russian speaker.

There is a so called Russian transliteration (Romanization of Russian) where any of 33 letters could be transformed to Latin directly. You may apply such a transliteration to decode Russian to Latin and vice versa in the background.

Something like this:

```
hostname:8888/index.cfm?foo=Solntsezaschitnye-ochki
```

Or just use an ID number instead of text if it is possible.